# A number theory problem, about prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $m_1, m_2, \ldots , m_r$, $r \geq 2$, be non zero integers which do not have a common
prime divisor. Show that there exists $a_1, \ldots , a_r \in \Bbb Z$, such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^r a_i \cdot m_i = 1$$

I am new in this area, any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Apply $au+bv = \gcd(a,b)$ (Bezout identity) $r$ times

Comment: Proving Bezout's identity (which everyone should do before they use it) is a bit irritating.  But it's a proof by ruduction.  If $a < b$ then $b= wa + r$ where $r < a$ and so if $r > 0$ then $\gcd(b,a)|r$ and we can repeat indefinitely.  If time we repeat, $a= zr + r_2$ ,we will get smaller and smaller remainders.   As there are only finitely many remainders will eventually get $r_{n-1}= v_n*r_n + 0; r_n=\gcd(a,b)$.  Then the values $u,v$ so that $au+bv = \gcd(a,b)$ can be calculate via the series of attempts.  You can think of it as a sort of proof by induction.

Comment: @fleablood It's not too irritating if we do it conceptually by importing elementary facets of ideas from group / ideal theory. Namely it is easy to prove that a nonempty set $S$ of integers $\rm\color{#c00}{closed\ under\ subtraction}$ has the form $\,S = d\Bbb Z\,$ where $d$ is the least nonnegative element in $\,S\,$ or, equivalently $\,d  = \gcd S.\,$ This viewpoint is presented in detail in my answer in the linked dupe. It's essence is clarified when one studies (cyclic) groups and (principal) ideals in abstract algebra.

Comment: "irritating" is subjective.   And if one hasn't studied group/ideal theory...  It's not really "irritating" per say, but ... well, I always found proofs where we assume least elements exist and reduction ad finitim to be ... well, "irratating" in the sense that as a student it feels uncertain that we are allowed to *do* that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT.- Choose $a_1,a_2\in \mathbb Z$ such that $a_1m_1=k$ and $a_2m_2=l-k$ so you get $a_1m_1+a_2m_2=l$. Iterate the procedure keeping in mind at the end that
if $(m,n)=1$ then $\mathbb Z=m\mathbb Z+n\mathbb Z$ by Bézout's identity.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What is $k,l$ ?

Comment: thanks for the help!

Comment: @reunds: are the resultant products of made multiplications. It was obvious for me and I sorry for not explain this.

Comment: @Huanzhen Zhang: You are welcome.